# How do I escape Nonprintable Characters

Tags: zig

I have the below code:

```
const std = @import("std");

fn getTLVForValue(writer: anytype, tagNum: []const u8, tagValue: []const u8) !void {
    _ = try writer.write(tagNum);;
    _ = try writer.writeByte(@intCast(tagValue.len));
    _ = try writer.write(tagValue);
}

pub fn main() !void {
    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    const allocator = arena.allocator();
    var qrCodeBuf = std.ArrayList(u8).init(allocator);
    defer qrCodeBuf.deinit();
    const writer = qrCodeBuf.writer();

    //1. Seller Name
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "01", "Bobs Basement Records");

    //2. VAT Registration
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "02", "312345678901233");

    //3. Time stamp
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "03", "12-12-2023");

    //4. tax Total
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "04", "1000");

    //5. Vat Total
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "05", "115");

    //6. Hashed XML
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "06", "dsds");

    //7. key
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "07", "125");

    //8. Signature
    try getTLVForValue(writer, "08", "dsfsd");

    std.debug.print("{any}\n", .{qrCodeBuf.items});

    std.debug.print("Hex string: {s}\n", .{std.fmt.fmtSliceHexUpper(qrCodeBuf.items)});
    // const hex = try std.fmt.allocPrint("{s}", .{std.fmt.fmtSliceHexUpper(qrCodeBuf.items)});

    const output_buffer = try allocator.alloc(u8, std.base64.standard.Encoder.calcSize(qrCodeBuf.items.len));
    defer allocator.free(output_buffer);
    const data = std.base64.standard.Encoder.encode(output_buffer, qrCodeBuf.items);
    std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{data});

    const decode_buf = try allocator.alloc(u8, try std.base64.standard.Decoder.calcSizeForSlice(data));
    try std.base64.standard.Decoder.decode(decode_buf, data);
    std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{decode_buf});
    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{std.zig.fmtEscapes(decode_buf)});

    try std.testing.expectEqualStrings(qrCodeBuf.items, decode_buf);
}
```

And it is giving me the final output as:

```
01\x15Bobs Basement Records02\x0f31234567890123303\n12-12-202304\x04100005\x0311506\x04dsds07\x0312508\x05dsfsd
```

But here I'm getting a noneprintable ASCII characters instead of the numbers, I get for example `\n` instead of `10` and `\x15` instead of `21` and so on as per the mapping showing [here](https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/lsp121/documents/ascii-npr.htm).

I'm opened for any alternate option to get the function `getTLVForValue` return the `TLV - Tag - Length - Value`, so that I get for example `0103xxxx` for a tag the is of the length `3` and having the tagNum as `01`.

I'm trying to write a code that is doing what is explained in the screen shoot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing values as bytes instead of formatting them as numbers:

```
try writer.writeByte(@intCast(tagValue.len));
```

Do this:

```
try writer.print("{}", .{ tagValue.len });
```